# How to create Batch tx?

Tags: batch, safe

How to create a batch tx as shown in the safe app where using the click of **Execute Batch** you can combine all the pending tx into one and execute them at once.

I am using this code:

```
const executeBatch = async() =>
  {
    var safeTransactionData = [];
    pendingTx.forEach(element => {
      var obj = {
        to: element['to'],
        data: (element['data']==null ? '0x': element['data']),
        value: element['value'],
        nonce: element['nonce']
      }
      safeTransactionData.push(obj);
    });
    const callsOnly = true;
    console.log("SafeTxData:",safeTransactionData);
    const safeSdk = await Safe.create(safeConfig);

    const safeTransaction = await safeSdk.createTransaction({safeTransactionData,callsOnly});
    const executeTxResponse = await safeSdk.executeTransaction(safeTransaction);
    const receipt = await executeTxResponse.transactionResponse?.wait();

    console.log('Transaction executed:');
    console.log(`https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/${receipt?.transactionHash}`);
  }
```

This combines all the tx data into one and executes one tx but the other pending tx remains there and doesn't get executed.

Answer (score 0):

My Idea: The external account sends a transaction to the contract, and the contract executes the batch transaction.